# LaTeX formula renderer for current Thunderbird

Tags: email, formulas

I would like to send e-mails with formulas. I use Thunderbird for mail composition. I have found

Equations:

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/equations/

and LaTeX it!:

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/latex-it

but they are not maintained and so I cannot install them on current Thunderbird.

Is there another method that works with a fresh Thunderbird?

Answer (score 2):

One relatively easy way is to insert a query for an online formula editor as an image. For example Codecogs has the following basic query string:

https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?your_formula_here

In Thunderbird you can use this with the <kbd>Insert</kbd>-<kbd>Image...</kbd> menu:

[image]

Note that a few characters need escaping in the query string, for example spaces are encoded as `&space;` and + is encoded as `&plus;`. If in doubt you can enter the formula on https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php to generate the query string.

Comment: This is actually pretty handy. It doesn't sound hard to write an extension that takes a Latex expression `exp` on the draft email body and replaces it with an image with location `https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?exp`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a gmail/Thunderbird add-on for this:

https://github.com/dominique-unruh/mathquill-for-gmail/wiki/Install-from-source

Comment: Did you manage to install it? I'm having trouble installing from source